# WM_LBUTTONDOWN not sent immediately when mouse button is down

Tags: c++, winapi, mouseevent, windows-messages

I can't detect precisely when the left mouse button is pressed with C++ in Windows 10 .

I tried 2 ways :

1. catching `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` message
2. using directly `GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON)`

Each time, the behavior is the same :
If I press the left button during one second,

1. the `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` is sent about 0.5 seconds after I pressed down
   the left button
2. the `GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON)` value returned changes exactly when WM_LBUTTONDOWN is sent, that means 0.5 seconds after I pressed the mouse button

the `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` is sent :

1. **if I only click** with the left button
2. if I press mouse down **while moving the mouse**

But I still don't know **how to detect immediately** when the left button is down in the case where I press the left button down a long time without moving the mouse.
Is there an event I don't know about?
Does Windows force us to think its way and use its "CLICK" and its "MOUSEDOWN" ? I mean, is there no way with windows to detect exactly when the mouse button is pressed ?
How to detect precisely when the left button is pressed with C++ in windows ?

---

EDIT :

Thank you for your answers.
I made a Minimal Complete and Verifiable code to show you.

The program below compiles with Visual C++ 2017
It shows a blue rectangle that moves each time GetMessage gets a message.
The rectangle becomes red and is translated down when WM_LBUTTONDOWN is detected.

As I described in my first post : you will see that the rectangle becomes red when you click or when you press the mouse button down while moving the mouse, but it takes about 0.5 seconds to become red if you press down the left button and don't move the mouse.

Thank you again for your help.

Here is the code :

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <GL/GL.h>
#include <math.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "opengl32.lib")

HDC   hdc;
HGLRC hrc;
bool ButtonL;

void MyDisplay()
{
    static float kk=0; kk+=0.04f;
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); glLoadIdentity();glTranslated(0.5*sin(kk),0,0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); glLoadIdentity();
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    if ((GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 0x100) != 0) glColor3f(1,0,0); else glColor3f(0,0,1);
    if (ButtonL) glTranslated(0,-0.5,0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);  glVertex2f(0,0);    glVertex2f(0,1);    glVertex2f(1,1);    glVertex2f(1,0);    glEnd();
}
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND   hWnd, UINT   uMsg, WPARAM   wParam, LPARAM  lParam)
{
        switch (uMsg)
        {
            case WM_LBUTTONDOWN  : ButtonL=true;  break;
            case WM_LBUTTONUP    : ButtonL=false; break;
        }
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd,uMsg,wParam,lParam);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ButtonL=false;
    WNDCLASS    wc;         
    RECT        WindowRect; 
    WindowRect.left   =(long)0; WindowRect.right  =(long)400;
    WindowRect.top    =(long)0; WindowRect.bottom =(long)300;
    HINSTANCE hInstance     = GetModuleHandle(NULL);           
    wc.style            = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
    wc.lpfnWndProc      = (WNDPROC) WndProc;                    
    wc.cbClsExtra       = 0;                            
    wc.cbWndExtra       = 0;                        
    wc.hInstance        = hInstance;                    
    wc.hIcon            = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);  
    wc.hCursor          = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);  
    wc.hbrBackground    = NULL;                         
    wc.lpszMenuName     = NULL;                         
    wc.lpszClassName    = "OpenGL";                     

    if (!RegisterClass(&wc)) return(0);

    AdjustWindowRectEx(&WindowRect, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, FALSE, WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE);    
    HWND hWnd=CreateWindowEx(   WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE,"OpenGL","Titre",WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN, 0, 0, 
                                WindowRect.right-WindowRect.left,WindowRect.bottom-WindowRect.top,NULL,NULL,hInstance,NULL);
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd=
    {   sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),1,PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,PFD_TYPE_RGBA,32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,              
        0,0,0,0, 0, 0, 0,16,0,0,PFD_MAIN_PLANE,0,0, 0, 0                            
    };

    hdc=GetDC(hWnd);
    GLuint PixelFormat=ChoosePixelFormat(hdc,&pfd);
    SetPixelFormat(hdc,PixelFormat,&pfd);
    hrc = wglCreateContext(hdc);
    wglMakeCurrent(hdc , hrc);
    ShowWindow(hWnd,SW_SHOW);               // Show The Window
    SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);              // Slightly Higher Priority
    SetFocus(hWnd);                     // Sets Keyboard Focus To The Window

    MSG Msg;
    while( GetMessage( &Msg, hWnd, 0, 0 ) != 0)
    { 
        TranslateMessage(&Msg); 
        DispatchMessage(&Msg); 
        MyDisplay();
        SwapBuffers(hdc);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is not sent, it is posted.  It instantly gets added to the message queue.  When your program reads it is unpredictable, it depends what else you do.  Like processing the previous message.  And yes, GetKeyState() is synchronous with your GetMessage() calls.  Consider using the MSG.time member, accuracy is about 16 msec by default.

Comment: Half a second doesn't sound right. Probably something wrong with your program. Only you can see it.

Comment: Post the relevant code

Comment: As said, 0.5 s is not normal. You don't notice a delay between clicking a button and the redrawing of the button in the pressed state. You *would* notice if there were a delay like 0.5 s which is well within human perception. I suppose you are either contesting the message queue or your measurement method is wrong. We can't know unless you post a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program works fine on my computer : I don't notice any delay when I press button down.
It seems windows messages are intercepted at a very low level on your computer.
Do you use a mouse recognition engine like "Sensiva" or "Just Gesture" or "Stroke it" ?
It could explain your problem.

Comment: As incredible as it seems, that was the solution ! Indeed, I use "Just Gesture" and if I disable this program, the 0.5 seconds delay disapears !
I don't understand how such programs can intercept windows messages and annoy my C++ program, but that is another question..!

Comment: Presumably "Just Gesture" doesn't create any problems for other programs running on your computer, but it does create problems for your program. What's the difference between your program and other programs? The glaring error in your message loop is a suspect.

Comment: "Just Gesture" created problems in other programs. When I open "Paint Shop Pro" while "Just Gesture" is active, if I take a red brush and if I press the mouse button down and if I keep the button pressed, there is half a second between the moment at which I press the mouse button and the moment at which Paint Shop Pro draws the red circle.